# Given a job id bring back a list jobs where job applications have been made to both jobs

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a requirement to find jobs and order them by the number of people who have applied for both jobs.

Here is what the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobApplication](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[JobId] [int] NULL,
[CvId] [int] NULL,
[MemberId] [int] NULL,
[CreatedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Source] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AgreedTerms] [bit] NULL,
[Authorised] [bit] NULL,
[ApplicationStatusId] [int] NULL)
```

And here is an attempt at the select statement.

```
SELECT     JobApplication.JobId, JobApplication_1.JobId AS AppliedFor, COUNT(JobApplication_1.JobId) AS AppliedForCount
FROM         JobApplication INNER JOIN
                  JobApplication AS JobApplication_1 ON JobApplication.CvId = JobApplication_1.CvId
WHERE JobApplication.JobId <> JobApplication_1.JobId                  
GROUP BY JobApplication.JobId, JobApplication_1.JobId
HAVING      (JobApplication.JobId = 4279)
ORDER BY AppliedForCount DESC
```

What the query needs to do is given a job id (4279) bring back a list jobs where job applications have been made to both jobs and rank the job list by number of applications shared between both jobs.

I didn't write the sample query so please and can't see where it is going wrong, can anyone help please?

Comment: Just to confirm: you want, for each job other than 4279, the number of applications that have been made for that job and 4279?

Comment: In what way is the results of this query not what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Scott what I need the query to do is for job A get the number of applications by cvId that appear in both jobs then order by the count, does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You keep saying "both jobs" and "both" means "two", but you're only providing a single JobID. Where's the "both" part of your question? Do you mean "applied for job 4279 and another job"?

Comment: Both meaning the id of the current job and the other job is one that holds applications with matching CVs for 4279 and itself (part of the query), any clearer?

Comment: So your question is "Given a job ID, can I find all applications that match it and have applied for job 4279 also?" If so, can you edit your question and say it like that (or more clearly if you can)? As written, your question is very hard to understand (as I'm sure you can see :)). Thanks. :)

Comment: @KenWhite Literally just LOL'd at your first comment at work thinking about Inigo Montoya saying that.  Made an ass of myself...

Comment: @Norla: Thanks. Just pictured that myself. <G>

Answer (score 1):

You can't display the other jobs that was applied for (well you can, but not as you described), but you can pick one of them with an aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT     
JobApplication.CvId, 
MIN(JobApplication_1.JobId) AS oneoftheAppliedFor, 
COUNT(*) AS AppliedForCount
FROM JobApplication 
INNER JOIN
    JobApplication AS JobApplication_1 
    ON JobApplication.CvId = JobApplication_1.CvId
    AND JobApplication.JobId = 4279
    AND JobApplication_1.JobId <> 4279
GROUP BY JobApplication.CvId
ORDER BY AppliedForCount DESC
```